# Latest data group-by without a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

This is a pretty common case, but I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

```
TABLE POSTS [ ID, USER_ID, TOPIC_ID, TIME ]
```

I want to get only the last post by each user on topic_id '1'

```
SELECT p.*
FROM
  posts p,
  (
    SELECT   user_id, max(time) mtime
    FROM     posts
    WHERE    topic_id = 1
    GROUP BY user_id
  ) pm
WHERE
  p.user_id = pm.user_id AND
  p.time    = pm.mtime
```

Is this correct? Is there a way to do this without the subquery?

Is there an option to get this data with spring-data queries, or this is a JDBC/stored procedure only thing?

Comment: This is correct - but always use explicit JOIN syntax

Comment: Ah, I spoke too soon. You need to include user_id in the subquery's SELECT, and best practice dictates that you *should* include topic_id in the GROUP BY (although it's not strictly necessary in this case)

Comment: Yeah, I messed up the translation from my domain to "posts" a bit, it should be "SELECT user_id, max(time)" instead of "topic_id" - edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the latest post for each user **without** using a subquery by using join:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM posts p
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts t
ON(p.user_id = t.user_id and p.time < t.time and t.topic_id = 1)
WHERE p.topic_id = 1 and t.topic_id is null
```

Comment: That's pretty interesting, I haven't seen this "trick" yet. However, it gets the last post on any topic by all users, not on topic '1' - is there a way to filter the results?

Comment: @qzshard Yes of course, inside the ON clause , updated the answer.. if it helped you I'll appreciate an upvote(^) and approval (V)

Comment: Old school. Good, but note that this method does not scale well (unlike the OP's own solution)

Comment: I really appreciate the effort, and maybe I'm doing something wrong - but I don't think this solution works. even with filter inside the join, you'll still be getting the max-time posts, not the max-time-per-topic posts.

Comment: @qzshard - to solve that just copy the check for topic id in to the WHERE clause as well (ie, in the ON clause check for _t.topic_id = 1_ and in the WHERE clause add AND _p.topic_id = 1_

Comment: this cannot work as given, every p.* row with topic_id <> 1 will be returned (because t.topic_id will be NULL) include the `and p.topic_id = 1` t the where clause would help

Comment: qzshard Try it now.. @Kickstart both can be in the ON clause

Comment: you still need it in the where clause. if p.topic_id > 1 exists then t.topic_id IS NULL for every such row...

Comment: But I filter only p.topic_id = 1, so >1 cannot be returned @Used_By_Already

Comment: @sagi - the check for p.topic_id must be in the WHERE clause because of the LEFT OUTER JOIN. Otherwise you just limit the join and do not limit the rows from posts returned.

Comment: @Kickstart same answer to you.

Comment: nice, it works now. the real question is - which is better performance-wise, this or the sub-query version?

Comment: Your subquery sulotion? Defenitly this

Comment: @qzshard - that will depend on the indexes (easily changed) and the data. If you have a fairly small number of users and a large number of topics then the sub query will return a small number of rows, hence the lack of an index on that join will be of minor importance. But the LEFT OUTER JOIN here would return a massive number of rows before excluding most of them on the WHERE clause which would slow things down. But with a large number of users each with a small number of topics the opposite is true.

Comment: There is a small number of "users" (not actual users, more like sources - ~40 and unlikely to ever change) and one topic per day (there are a few years of data, however), so with an index on user and topic, things should work fine?

Comment: btw, I'm aware that's not a lot of data (but it runs thousands of times per hour), it's more of learning about how things work in the DB. Are there any sources you can recommend about DB perf?

Comment: @qzshard - afraid nothing overall good that I have found to recommend. Joining 40 times to a sub query is (even when it doesn't use an index for the join) probably a non issue performance wise, but with thousands of occurrences of a topic could cause major problems for this solution. The join will result in a number of temp rows equal to the factorial (I think) of the number of rows! For 365 days with one topic a day for one user that is 2.510412867 E+778 rows resulting from the join before the WHERE clause is actioned.

Comment: @qzshard - best to try the solutions here (yours, this solution, mine and that by MotoGP) on your real data and check the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure how to avoid `sub-query` here but another way to do this will be

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   posts p
WHERE  p.time = (SELECT Max(time) mtime
                 FROM   posts pm
                 WHERE  pm.topic_id = 1
                        AND p.user_id = pm.user_id)
```

Window Function `Row_number` will be very helpful in such cases unfortunately `Mysql` does not supports

Comment: thanks, this is another way I've seen in other questions. But in terms of performance, isn't this a very intense query (compared to the original)?

Comment: @qzshard- you can test that with your real time data

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that avoids a sub query (but again might not be that quick) is using substring_index ordered by time descending for each field you want the latest from, and then using SUBSTRING_INDEX to just grab the first entry returned by SUBSTRING_INDEX.

```
SELECT user_id, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(`id` ORDER BY `time` DESC), ',', 1),
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(`topic_id` ORDER BY `time` DESC), ',', 1),
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(`time` ORDER BY `time` DESC), ',', 1)
FROM posts
WHERE    topic_id = 1
GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score -1):

To do it without a subquery, use `HAVING`.

```
SELECT   user_id, topic_id,  time
FROM     posts
WHERE    topic_id = 1
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING time = max(time)
```

Comment: `HAVING time =..` is this allowed in `Mysql`

Comment: Haven't tried but I imagine so:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: doesn't work, you can't use "having" in a single row context

Comment: You would think it work, but it doesn't